# Как запускать gui приложение Qt без консоли?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Проблема такова : исполняемый файл готового приложения запускается вместе с консолью позади. Параметр "Run in terminal" снят, приложение создано в формате Qt widgets, сборщик - CMake, компилятор MinGW. Пытался создать новое приложение под qmake - всё нормально, никаких проблем и запусков gui с консолью нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему с CMake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена : к add_executable(projName ...) после projName добавляем WIN32

Comment: Кроме этого может быть ещё баг в Qt Creator. Параметр Run in terminal не всегда срабатывает. Иногда нужно его включить и выключить.

Comment: Ох! Наконец-то я нашёл ответ на этот вопрос. Казалось бы простой вопрос, но как я ни пытался найти это через гугл, ни в русском, ни в английском, ни в официальной документации, ни на ютубе -- всё было тщетно. В паре мест лишь советовали добавить параметр -mwindow, в другом месте ещё пару ключей. Но у меня пока нет чёткого понимания как работает CMake и куда тут в CLion подставлять эти ключи. В общем, ничего не получалось. А тут бац и такое просто решение. Огромное вам спасибо и плюсик!

Comment: @gugglegum да, сам год назад мучался долго)) И с CMake  действительно всё очень неоднозначно и на старте сложно. Возможно, стоит для начала поразбираться с чем-то более конкретным типа утилиты Make (если конечно работаете на Linux). А потом уже юзать этот менее понятный завод под названием CMake )) Мне после этого стало чуть проще смотреть на него.